# Are there known algorithms to find a line that intersects a given set of segments?

Tags: computational-geometry, combinatorics

Are there known algorithms to find a line that intersects a given set of segments?

In:
A finite set of segments.

Out:
A line that cross all these segments or explicit answer that there is no such line.

I've tried wiki and general algorithms books but found none.

Comment: What is the complexity of this *combinatorial* solution ?

Comment: I don't know what "combinatorial" means.  I encourage you to [edit] the post to show the best algorithm you are aware of, and what its running time is.  I also suggest that you elaborate  on what you mean by "find a line..." (what are the inputs to this problem?  what is the desired output?) and explain what you mean by "faster" (do you care about practical running time? theoretical worst-case asymptotic complexity? something else?).

Comment: Combinatorial means usually brute force.

Comment: Such line might not exist, so you need to formulate your problem more accurately - for example, find a line, which intersects **maximal** number of segments. Please see here for a classic solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479840/how-to-find-a-line-that-stabs-the-maximum-possible-number-of-segments

Comment: @HEKTO, I thought that it is obvious that such a line may or may not exist. In such a case, answer NO is enough. But maximal number of segments is also interesting though, thank you for your link.